# Android OpenGL ES 2: Introduction to VBOs

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-buffer

Can someone offer a tutorial for using vertex buffer objects (VBOs) in Android?

I am working on a 2D HUD which is drawn using OpenGL ES 2 on Android.

Answer (score -1):

The best OpenGL ES tutorials are not specifically for Android, but the way VBOs are used will be directly portable.  The best OpenGL ES examples are in the [PowerVR SDK](http://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/).

There is also a collection of relevant articles on my [blog](http://montgomery1.com/opengl/) that will help too.

Answer (score -1):

Here's some:

- [Most basic working vbo example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091570/most-basic-working-vbo-example)
- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples