# Android GLES20 - cannot create VBO - JNI ERROR

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I'm creating a VBO with GLES20 in Android and am currently running into a JNI error. I doublechecked capacity and value counts. I also checked, if the buffer (STANDARD_QUAD in my code) gets and ID.
I really don't know how to continue. I tested on 2 different physical devices and one emulator, so the fault must be in the code somewhere.

Code:

```
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(30 * 4);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    buffer.asFloatBuffer().put(new float[]{
            0, 0, 0,    0,0,
            0,  1, 0,   0,1,
             1, 0, 0,   1,0,
             1,  1, 0,  1,1,
            1, 0, 0,    1,0,
             0, 1, 0,   0,1
    });
    buffer.flip();

    int[] vboids = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, vboids, 0);
    STANDARD_QUAD = vboids[0];
    System.out.println("init vbo (std quad): " + STANDARD_QUAD + ", buffer.capacity: " + buffer.capacity());
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, STANDARD_QUAD);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.capacity(), buffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Output:

```
init vbo (std quad): 1, buffer.capacity: 120
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[13,tid=19730,Runnable,Thread*=0xb4e08800,peer=0x12c07060,"GLThread 13050"] called too many critical releases
     in call to ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical
     from void android.opengl.GLES20.glBufferData(int, int, java.nio.Buffer, int)
 "GLThread 13050" prio=5 tid=13 Runnable
   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c07060 self=0xb4e08800
   | sysTid=19730 nice=-11 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xaf854300
   | state=R schedstat=( 73594541 5530250 17 ) utm=6 stm=1 core=5 HZ=100
   | stack=0xa10fe000-0xa1100000 stackSize=1036KB
   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
   native: #00 pc 00004c58  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
   native: #01 pc 000034c1  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
   native: #02 pc 0025c5ad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
   native: #03 pc 0023f8cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+162)
   native: #04 pc 000b313d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+620)
   native: #05 pc 000b386d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
   native: #06 pc 000b6b65  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1436)
   native: #07 pc 000c1de7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(_JNIEnv*, _jarray*, void*, int)+42)
   native: #08 pc 000684d1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
   native: #09 pc 000736e3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
   native: #10 pc 01574071  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_opengl_GLES20_glBufferData__IILjava_nio_Buffer_2I+128)
   at android.opengl.GLES20.glBufferData(Native method)
   at my.package.glsl.GuiProgram.initQuad(GuiProgram.java:66)
   at my.package.glsl.GuiProgram.onCreated(GuiProgram.java:111)
   at my.package.glsl.Program.create(Program.java:67)
   at my.package.glsl.Shaders.initialize(Shaders.java:26)
   at my.package.myapplication.FullscreenActivity.renderGL(FullscreenActivity.java:66)
   at my.package.myapplication.FullscreenActivity.access$000(FullscreenActivity.java:22)
   at my.package.myapplication.FullscreenActivity$1.render(FullscreenActivity.java:42)
   at my.package.opengl.OpenglRenderer.onDrawFrame(OpenglRenderer.java:38)
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1561)
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1278)
```

**EDIT:**

Changing the code to the following, the error changes.

```
    FloatBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(30 * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    buffer.put(new float[]{
            //...
    });
    buffer.flip();
    //...
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.capacity() * 4, buffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The error changes to `JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray was null`. But definitely buffer != null. It's really weird.

Comment: Is this line `GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.capacity(), buffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);` perhaps wrapped in a mutex?

Comment: @Shark if you mean wether it is synchronized then no, except `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1561)` is synchronized.

Comment: Read the stacktrace again, the line I mentioned is problematic since somehow it calls `ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical` which causes the `called too many critical releases` error, which may or may not be tied to some mutex (see this `held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)` part?)

Comment: @Shark What do you mean by plain array? `GLES20.glBufferData(...)` only accepts `java.nio.Buffer` objects.

Comment: You're right. I guess I don't know then :/ Take a look at a few more links like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053786/opengl-es-2-on-android-how-to-use-vbos?rq=1)

Comment: @Shark I moved the code block directly to the `onSurfaceCreated(...)` method of the Renderer to be sure no custom synchronization is done. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by using `buffer.position(0)` instead of `buffer.flip()`.

According to the docs `buffer.flip()` should work correct, as it is also setting the position to 0. The only difference is that `flip()` is also setting the `limit` to the last position (see [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip()) for more information).
So it's possible that the limit causes the weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

try allocateDirect, instead of allocate.

allocate cost more time that allocateDirect, cause it allocate memory in JVM.